# How could this Y' same as this Y combinator itself?

Tags: lambda-calculus, y-combinator, fixpoint-combinators

I see this in [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_combinator#Other_fixed-point_combinators):

```ml
Y' = SSK(S(K(SS(S(SSK))))K)
```

And I [understand](https://gist.github.com/ypa-y-yhm/3dd8f45ceb9b0a1bb14273c0ccf60210#y) why it corresponds to this lambda expression `Y' = (λab.aba) (λab.a(bab))`

But I don't know how can this same as `X = λa.(λx.xx)(λx.a(xx))` or `X = λa.(λx.a(xx))(λx.a(xx))`.

Can `Y'` trans to `X` by *β-reduces* or some other way and how ? Thanks ...

Answer (score 0):

I know it !

We can make this:

```ml
 = S(K(SS(S(SSK))))K = λab.a(bab)
```

So

```ml
Y' 
 = (λb'.(λab.a(bab))b'(λab.a(bab)))
 = λx.(λab.a(bab))x(λab.a(bab))
 = λx.x

Y' 
 = SSK(S(K(SS(S(SSK))))K)
 = (λb'.(λab.a(bab))b'(λab.a(bab)))
 = (λb'.(b'((λab.a(bab))b'(λab.a(bab)))))
 = (λb'.(b'(b'((λab.a(bab))b'(λab.a(bab))))))
 = (λb'.(b'(b'(b'((λab.a(bab))b'(λab.a(bab)))))))
 = (λb'.(b'(b'(b'(b'((λab.a(bab))b'(λab.a(bab))))))))
 = ...

Y' 
 = λx.x
 = λx.x(x)
 = λx.x(x(x))
 = ...

Y' f 
 = f
 = f(f)
 = f(f(f))
 = ...

Y' f = f (Y' f)
```

So

```ml
Y 
 = S(K(SII))(S(S(KS)K)(K(SII)))
 = λa.(λb.a(bb))(λc.a(cc))

Y f 
 = (λb.f(bb)) (λc.f(cc))
 = f ((λb.f(bb)) (λc.f(cc)))
 = f (Y f)
 = f (f (Y f))
 = f (f (f (Y f)))
 = ...

Y f = f (Y f)
Y' f = f (Y' f)

Y = Y'

S(K(SII))(S(S(KS)K)(K(SII))) = SSK(S(K(SS(S(SSK))))K)
```

(I don't know did that correct ...)